# Jackson builder pattern get value from parent

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am trying to obtain a value from a parent node using Jackson.

I know this is possible to achieve with custom deserialisers, but then there is too much boilerplate because you suddenly have to handle everything manually.

It sounds like something quite simple but didn't find a way to do it.

To illustrate what I want - If we have a simple `User` with `Address`...

```
@JsonDeserialize(builder = User.Builder.class)
public class User
{
  private long id;
  private String firstName;
  private Address address;
  ...

  public static class Builder
  {
    public Builder withId(long id);
    public Builder withFirstName(String value);
    public Builder withAddress(Address address);
    public User create();
  }
}
```

If we have the same for address

```
@JsonDeserialize(builder = Address.Builder.class)
public class Address
{
  ...

  public static class Builder
  {
    public Builder withUserId(long id); // is there a way to ask for the parent id here?
    public Builder withStreetName(String value);
    public Address create();
  }
}
```

Sample input:

```
{
    "id": 7,
    "firstName" : "John",
    "lastName" : "Smith",
    "address" : {
        "streetName": "1 str"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think you can with any of the existing Jackson code. The only thing I believe that can cross parent/child relationships like that is type serialization/deserialization and the `UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE` support.

If you want something like that, you'd either need to use a custom deserializer for `User`, or customize the `User` constructor to build a new address with the correct UserId before adding it to the builder's internal state. Here's an example (using Lombok to handle the boilerplate generation of builders):

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonPOJOBuilder;

import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Value;
import lombok.experimental.Wither;

public class Scratch {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String json = "{\"id\":1234,\"address\":{\"street\":\"123 Main St.\"}}";

        User user = mapper.readValue(json, User.class);

        System.out.println(user.toString());

    }


    @Value
    @JsonDeserialize(builder = User.UserBuilder.class)
    public static class User {
        private final int id;
        private final Address address;


        @Builder(toBuilder = true)
        public User(int id, Address address) {
            this.id = id;
            // Build a new address with the user's ID
            this.address = address.withUserId(id);
        }

        @JsonPOJOBuilder(withPrefix = "")
        public static class UserBuilder {}
    }


    @Value
    @Builder(toBuilder = true)
    @JsonDeserialize(builder = Address.AddressBuilder.class)
    public static class Address {

        @Wither
        private final int userId;

        private final String street;

        @JsonPOJOBuilder(withPrefix = "")
        public static class AddressBuilder {}
    }

}
```

This consumes the following json:

```
{
    "id":      1234,
    "address": {
        "street": "123 Main St."
    }
}
```

and produces the following output:

```
Scratch.User(id=1234, address=Scratch.Address(userId=1234, street=123 Main St.))
```